# C# Creating a simple hash/key from an object

Tags: c#, hash

I have a service application that deals with various remote requests to other systems. Each request requires an OAuth access token relevant for that remote system. I want to cache the tokens in memory, at least whilst the token is still valid. Then when a new request needs sending, if I have a valid access token already, I can use that rather than asking the Auth server for a new one. I would like to store them in a dictionary, but I'm struggling when it comes to the dictionary key. Is there a way to hash the credentials object to produce a hash key? I tried .GetHashCode() but that seemed to be different each time. Is there a better approach? This isn't a hash for security, its about generating a short but unique key for each credentials object.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't simply use some kind of identifying key (i.e. "KEY_FOR_SERVICE_A", "KEY_FOR_SERVICE_B", etc.)

Comment: ^^ In other words: What makes the keys unique? And if you can answer this question, you need to incorporate that into your desired key.

Comment: If you just want a service to generate a token, save it, and store the id, perhaps you could have a `Dictionary<Guid, string>` or something.

Comment: If you don't know which key to use, how do you know which object from the dictionary you're supposed to be using?

Comment: Thanks all. I could generate my own key by concatenating all the relevant properties, like the auth server's URL, the Client ID, the Client Secret, the Username and the Password... but that creates quite a long string/key. I just thought if there was a simple way to create a consistent hash from an object/class that might be better.

Comment: Is that really needed all? I would have guessed, that for example, the ClientID would take precedence over username and password. In other words: For every ClientId, username and password would also change, right? So for building a unique key, it would suffice to incorporate the ClientID.

Comment: I would definitely put the password in the hashkey. You should be careful storing those things.